# java application to access amazon simpledb domains

Tags: amazon-simpledb

I need to make an application in java which would be able to access the domains in simpledb. I have created the account and generated access keys. the tools - sdb explorer, scratchpad, and the sdb tool for firefox are not working. how should I start.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct `region and endpoint` to which your `domain` belongs. `Amazon SimpleDB` supports 8 region end points.

Here is the link :
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#sdb_region

Here is sample code:

```
AmazonSimpleDBConfig theConfig = new AmazonSimpleDBConfig();
theConfig.ServiceURL = myEndpoint;  //where myEndPoint is the region endpoint you are interested in
AmazonSimpleDBClient simpleDbClient= new AmazonSimpleDBClient(myKey, mySecretKey, theConfig);
String selectExpression = "select * from LogTable";
SelectRequest selectRequestAction = new SelectRequest();
selectRequestAction.SelectExpression = selectExpression;
selectRequestAction.NextToken = null;
SelectResponse selectResponse = simpleDbClient.Select(selectRequestAction);
SelectResult selectResult = selectResponse.SelectResult;
List<Item> itemList = selectResult.Item;
```

The same thing is applicable to your `third party tool`. If you are using **SDB Explorer** then after successfully logged-in you should see the list of regions and endpoints at left-hand side corner. You should explore the correct region end point in which you can find your created `domain`.